# "appcompat_v7" project is created automatically after creating a new project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

After creating any new android project, Eclipse automatically creates a "appcompat_v7" project without any files under /src. I have no idea how or why Eclipse is creating this project. I am also getting a weird error.

[image]

As you can see the AndroidManifest.xml exists in the project!

EDIT1: After cleaning the project the weird error was gone, but I'd still like to know why the appcompat_v7 is created.

EDIT2: I also noticed that Eclipse is automatically creating a new layout, fragment_main.xml, under /res/layout. WHY??

I have created a new Workspace, and tried it several times. But I still have this problem.

EDIT3: If you choose the minimum SDK version after API 14 you won't get this support folder.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Recently updated some of my SDK stuff and now every time I create an app this gets created as well. I also am running into a problem where the app has dependencies for appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar and libs\android-support-v4.jar (two different android-support-v4.jars) so I have to work around that every time. Hope someone can help you out with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this problem last night.  I was doing several things including updating the SDK manager.  I had to back off the **Android SDK Tools** to Rev. 22.3 and **Android SDK Platform-tools** to 19.

opus44

Comment: How can i select a lower revision? i only have 23.0.5 under "Android SDK MANAGER"

Answer (score 7):

first clean and build the appcompat_v7 project and then clean and build your project. it worked

Answer (score 6):

I installed "Android support repository" from Android SDK Manager/Extras and the errors are gone.

Comment: Installing Android Suppor Repository did not work in my case.

Comment: In my case I install Android Support Library (Obsolete) works for me

Answer (score 6):

**Do as follows to overcome this issue, this works for me. Create project as usual than follow below steps**

```
Step-1:
```

Right Click on your Project -> Properties -> Android -> In Library panel, **remove** appcompat_v7 library, Apply and Ok

```
Step-2:
```

In Project goto res -> values -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `android:Theme.Light`

```
Step-3:
```

In Project goto res -> values-v11 -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

```
Step-4:
```

In Project goto res -> values-v14 -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
Step-5:
```

In Project goto menu -> main.xml **remove** these lines in menu tag:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
```

and in item tag **change** this line from `app:showAsAction="never"` to `android:showAsAction="never"`

In project, goto res -> layout -> **delete fragment.xml**

```
Step-6:
```

In MainActivity **extends Activity** not ActionBarActivity and finally your MainActivity.java after **remove unnecessary code**, looks like this:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Enjoy:)**

Answer (score 1):

import the android project to the workspace from /extras/android/support/ then navigate to your current project and add it as dependency : Project > Properties > Android > Add (the imported project) . You should be able to see a Green tick next to the imported project. Remove the old reference that you lost/deleted. A reference about what this library is can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Answer (score -1):

I on ubuntu only clean up aappcompat_v7 source code it worked well for me