# Can Eclipse be prevented from creating additional appcompat_v7 projects?

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse now has this nice feature where it makes a "Support Project" for you with the name `appcompat_v7`, automatically linking both support-v4 & -v7 for you and giving you XML attributes only available in the later SDK levels. However, whenever I create a new project, instead of linking to the original support project, it creates a new, identical support project with the name `appcompat_v7_2`, `appcompat_v7_3`, and so forth.

Is there any way we can prevent Eclipse from creating additional clones?

Comment: Thanks for this question, I was about to post the similar point. Hence +1 and Thumbs-up :)

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through couple of indicators in SO about this topic like

a)[Why does Eclipse automatically add appcompat v7 library support whenever I create a new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a) 
b) and ["appcompat_v7" project is created automatically after creating a new project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240970/appcompat-v7-project-is-created-automaticaly-after-creating-a-new-project-in-e)

But no where it is answered through which we can ignore the support library creation. What I understood is that,

**It is considered good practice to include the support library by default because of the large diversity of devices and the fragmentation that exists between the different versions of Android (and thus, of the provided APIs).**

**But you can deactivate automatic inclusion of the Support Library by default in Eclipse.**

Also I went through this - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66975 which is a much better discussion on this context.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I don't want to deactivate it, I just want all projects that need it to use JUST ONE appcompat_v7. I don't want to fill up my workspace with appcompat_v7_X. It doesn't make sense to keep doing this and it gets very irritating. The only solution I've figured out so far is to simply just keep on deleting "appcompat_v7" when I want to create a new project. It'll recreate it automatically and everything works ok, but I would like not to do it this way and instead just set it so all projects link to a single appcompat_v7... I hope this helps a little. I know it's annoying.