# appcombat_v7 adds automatically after creating a new project in eclipse

Tags: android

I have Already tried these links but,my problem did not solve.

[Can Eclipse be prevented from creating additional appcompat_v7 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725877/can-eclipse-be-prevented-from-creating-)       additional-appcompat-v7-projects/22726069#22726069

[Can Eclipse be prevented from creating additional appcompat_v7 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725877/can-eclipse-be-prevented-from-creating-additional-appcompat-v7-projects/22726069#22726069)

Comment: because you have the latest revision of ADT, It comes auto

Comment: You mean it will create with every new android project.

Comment: Yes.. it is a part of the new ADT plugins..

Comment: A fix is pending, see comment 2 in http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the new-activity wizard, whether individually or via the "Create activity" checkbox. That is what is adding `appcompat` to your project, if the activity template you choose calls for it.