# Problems with new ADT bundle

Tags: android, eclipse

i have recently down loaded **new ADT bundle with ADK version19** from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and unfortunately i have deleted my old ADT bundle from my system :(

Now i am facing many problems with new ADT bundle like

> 1) Every time it is creating **appcompat_v7** project while i am creating new project.
>
> 2)While rotating emulator App is not rotating and i am unable to create emulator with old SDK versions.

So,Please help me how to resolve from these problem or provide some URL/help how to i can go to **old eclipse**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find older versions of Eclipse ADT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)

Comment: I think you should read official documentation here [Setting Up the ADT Bundle](http://http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) and also [SDK Manager](http://http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) and then try to go through it. By the way, I have answered your original question so you should accept my answer. You have another problem now. It means that you have another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download older ADT Bundles here:

- [adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030.zip)
- [adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip)

and yet older here:

- [adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514.zip](http://ftp.bistu.edu.cn/Develop/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514.zip)
- [adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514.zip](http://ftp.bistu.edu.cn/Develop/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514.zip)

You can download older Android platforms using SDK Manager in Eclipse.

[image: Android SDK Manager icon in Eclipse]

Comment: You can also download SDK platform for Android 4.3 (API 18) using Android SDK Manager which is integrated part of Eclipse and then you can create Android virtual device that has no problem with changing layout orientation.

Comment: Still i have the Problem.I downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030 and it contains only "android-19" in platforms folder.so i am unable to achieve "Rotation" problem. Form where i can get old API's like Android-17,Android-11,Android-14.....

Comment: @user3601427 See my comment above. You can download "Android-18" and other platforms using SDK Manager which is in Eclipse.

Comment: @user3601427 I have edited my answer. I added the picture where the Android SDK Manager icon is shown in the red square. Use it for downloading older Android platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your help but in system SDK manager is not working properly.Could you provide direct link to download ? And it is showing  below error **02:09 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-05-06 09:02:09 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-05-06 09:02:09 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified.**

Comment: @user3601427 I think you should read official documentation here [Setting Up the ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) and also [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) and then try to go through it. By the way, I have answered your original question so you should accept my answer. You have another problem now. It means that you have another question.

Answer (score 0):

**"how to i can go to old eclipse"**

[DUPLICATE QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)
Quoting the above link

> You can find the old versions of the ADT at the following URLs (it
>   looks like Google keeps them around, but doesn't advertise how to
>   locate them).
>
> http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.5.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.6.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.7.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.8.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.9.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.1.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-14.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-15.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.3.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.0.1.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.1.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.1.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.4.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.5.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.2.0.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.2.1.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip You can use these in
>   Eclipse by first downloading the desired ADT zip to your local drive,
>   then choosing "Install New Software", "Add Site", "Archive".

---

**1)**
appcompat_v7 such folders are just for its **version compatibility** , it wont affect your project , *do check if its a problem to you->* [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240970/appcompat-v7-project-is-created-automaticaly-after-creating-a-new-project-in-e)

[info on appcompact folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543448/1897935)

> This is part of the ADT/SDK update and it is not a bad thing to happen. It ensures that your app has full support of the ActionBarActivity that was implemented in API 14+.....

---

**2)** quoting a soluton to duplicate question , [.....DUPLICATE QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4)

> These appear to be bugs in the Android 4.4 emulator

Comment: What do you mean by "it wont affect your project"? Obviously it does, because your project relies upon this library project. Note however that the `appcompat_v7` project gets only created if you are in need of the support library, e.g. using functionality that is not natively provided by `minSdkVersion`. Personally I don't like it, but it seems that there is no other way to reliable bundle a library with resources attached to it.

Comment: **i have updated the post with link to solve it** , since its for compatibility it normally does not stops the project